# gnuplot xrange from file

Tags: datetime, plot, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to plot different temperature measurements with a timestamp from a data file like this:

```
”id";"timestamp";"1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6";"7";"8";"9";"10";"11";"12";"13";"14";"15";"16";"17";"18";"19";"20";"21";"22";"23";"24"
"925";"2017-02-22 06:49:29";"68";"69";"56";"76";"88";"95";"96";"104";"94";"177";"85";"80";"84";"92";"109";"58";"45";"49";"55";"13620";"132";"105";"54";"57"
"926";"2017-02-22 06:49:34";"69";"68";"56";"76";"89";"95";"97";"104";"95";"177";"85";"79";"84";"92";"117";"58";"125";"49";"56";"13620";"132";"105";"54";"58"
"927";"2017-02-22 06:49:40";"68";"68";"56";"76";"88";"94";"96";"104";"95";"177";"85";"79";"85";"92";"90";"58";"465";"50";"57";"13620";"132";"105";"54";"58"
"928";"2017-02-22 06:49:46";"68";"68";"57";"76";"88";"94";"96";"105";"94";"178";"84";"79";"185";"93";"104";"58";"46";"50";"57";"13620";"132";"105";"54";"58"
"929";"2017-02-22 06:49:52";"69";"69";"56";"76";"88";"94";"96";"105";"94";"178";"84";"80";"185";"93";"104";"58";"46";"50";"57";"13620";"132";"105";"54";"58"
```

Plotting the temperature against the "id" works fine, but connecting it to the timestamp doesn't work yet.
I'm setting the format for the xdate to time and specify the format like this:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\””
#set xrange ['"2017-02-23 05:00"':'"2017-02-23 17:00"']

set tics font",8"
set link x2
set x2tics format "%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M" time offset 0,-1
set xtics format ""
```

For not setting the xrange the plots are looking good but gives me the following,

```
set xrange [ * : * ] noreverse nowriteback  # (currently ["\"1970-01-01 00:15:00??":"\"1970-01-01 03:00:00??"] )
```

which I would like to change to the actual timestamp from my file. 
If I set it manually,

```
set xrange ['"2017-02-23 05:00"':'"2017-02-23 17:00"']
```

the time on the axis is correct, but no plots.

Plotting the data directly with the timestamp only gives one value, also with the wrong time axis.

I tried to define the x2ticlabels(2) but it didn't worked and gave me an error

```
plot    raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($12/10):x2tic(2)
"wrx_temperature1.1.gp", line 68: warning: add_tic_user: list sort error
```

I tried to figure out how to get it to work but right now I'm just trying the same ideas that don't work over and over again.

Maybe someone had the same problem and found a solution or got some different ways how to find a solution for this?

The gnuplot that I'm using is Version 5.0 patchlevel 5    last modified 2016-10-02

I attached a picture of my current plot.
[image: Here]

And here the code that I'm using:

```
    #raw_temperatures_datafilename = './../../../../measuring_data/wrx01_data_20170221x0X/20170221x00/raw_temperatures.csv'
raw_temperatures_datafilename = 'raw_temperatures.csv'
set datafile separator ";"

## 20170221x01 (...6020): Prozessbereich
# csvminline = 500
# csvmaxline = 3300
csvminline = -1
csvmaxline = -1

linewidth = 0.8

set style line 1 lw linewidth lt rgb "#CC0000"
set style line 2 lw linewidth lt rgb "#003399"
set style line 3 lw linewidth lt rgb "#009900"
set style line 4 lw linewidth lt rgb "#000000"
set style line 5 lw linewidth lt rgb "#0099FF"
set style line 6 lw linewidth lt rgb "#CC9900"

# set key autotitle columnhead
# unset key


### output
## use svg
 set terminal svg size 1920,1200 fname 'Verdana' fsize 8
 set terminal png size 2400,1400 font 'Verdana,8'
 set output raw_temperatures_datafilename.'.png'
## use screen
#set terminal wxt size 1800,900 enhanced font 'Verdana,8' persist

set key right top
set key box opaque
set grid
set lmargin 10
set rmargin 10

set multiplot # layout 3,1

set size 1, 0.7
set origin 0, 0.3
set bmargin 0

set title "Temperaturverlauf\n[Temperatur]=grad Celsius"

## first graph
set xdata time
set timefmt "\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\""
# set xrange ['"2017-02-23 05:00"':'"2017-02-23 17:00"']
set tics font",8"
set link x2
set x2tics format "%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M" time offset 0,-1
set format x ""
set yrange [0:550]
set ytics 0,50,500
set ylabel "Reaktor und Prozess"
plot    raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($12/10) title 'MARTY unten; E17 [10]' with lines ls 1, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($23/10) title 'MARTY oben; E10 [21]' with lines ls 2, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($11/10) title 'Separator; E16 0x09 [9]' with lines ls 3, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($16/10) title 'Separator Zuf¸hrung; E15 0x06 [14]' with lines ls 1, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($17/10) title 'Separator Abgang; 0x0D [15]' with lines ls 5, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($18/10) title 'Br¸cke; E20 0x29 [16]' with lines ls 4, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($3/10) title 'Fackelrohr; E19 0x00 [1]' with lines ls 4

#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($18/10) title '[16] 0x29 E20 Br¸cke' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($3/10) title '[1] 0x00 E19 Fackelrohr' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($4/10) title '[2] 0x01' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($5/10) title '[3] 0x02' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($6/10) title '[4] 0x20' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($7/10) title '[5] 0x22' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($8/10) title '[6] 0x23' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($9/10) title '[7] 0x25' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($15/10) title '[13] 0x27' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($13/10) title '[11] 0x28' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($14/10) title '[12] 0x26' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($10/10) title '[8] 0x07 Separator Zuf¸hrung' with lines, \
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($21/10) title '[19] 0x0E Eintrag' with lines
#raw_temperatures_datafilename using ($1):($24/10) title '[22] ' with lines

unset x2tics

## second graph
unset title
set size 1.0, 0.15
set origin 0.0, 0.15
set tmargin 0
set yrange [0:240]
set ytics 0,50,220
set ylabel "Prozessgas"
plot    raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($19/10) title 'Prozessgas ein; 0x10 [17]' with lines ls 1, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($20/10) title 'Prozessgas aus; 0x11 [18]' with lines ls 2

## third graph
set bmargin
set size 1.0, 0.15
set origin 0.0, 0.0
set tmargin 0
set xtics format "%H:%M" time
set yrange [0:55]
set ytics (0,10,20,30,40,50)
set ylabel "Kondensation"
plot    raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($25/10) title 'K¸hlwasser ein; 0x16 [23]' with lines ls 1, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($26/10) title 'K¸hlwasser aus; 0x17 [24]' with lines ls 2, \
        raw_temperatures_datafilename every ::csvminline::csvmaxline using ($1):($22/10) title 'Sensor K¸hlwasserbeh‰lter; [20]' with lines ls 3

unset multiplot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I use something like

```
set terminal pngcairo size 960,400
set output "times.png"

set datafile separator ";"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# adjust the plot on the picture
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.9
set xtics 10
# end adjust

plot "raw_temperatures.csv" u 2:3 w l
```

This is the result:

[image: x date and time]

I'm not sure about your script, but have you tried something like `... using ($2):($19/10) ...` instead of `... using ($1):($19/10) ...`? It might be that you simply try to read the first column, the id column, as a timestamp. In this case gnuplot would interpret the id as seconds starting at 1970-01-01 00:00:00.

---

**Update**

If you simply want to mirror the axis labels, this might help:

```
set terminal pngcairo size 960,400
set output "timesc.png"

# datafile
set datafile separator ";"
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# x1 axis (bottom)
set xdata time
set format x "%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M:%S"
set xtics  10    # A tic every 10 seconds.

# x2 axis (top)
set x2data time
set format x2 "%Y-%m-%d\n%H:%M:%S"
set x2tics 10 offset 0,-1  # A tic every 10 seconds. Small adjustment to fit on screen.
# set x2range ...

# plot adjustments
set rmargin at screen 0.93

plot "raw_temperatures.csv" u 2:3 w l lw 2
```

This is the result:

[image: x labels mirrored]

If you want to plot against x2, the plot command must be changed:

```
plot "raw_temperatures.csv" u 2:9 w l lw 2 axes x2y1, \
     "raw_temperatures.csv" u 2:8 w l lw 2
```

Comment: If I'm using the time stamp ($2) for the plot, it's only plotting one point and still with the wrong dates. I hoped I could plot the data with the ID and simply change the text at the xaxis. I don't know what I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What happens if you copy the script from my answer, does it work as expected? Can you convert it step by step to your answer and check which step fails?

Comment: I might understand you wrong, but the script you have posted uses ($1) instead of ($2).

Comment: The script you posted works like a charm. Thank you very much. 
I'm trying to get the x data to the x2 axis, does this work too? I tried it in your code but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I used ($1) instead of ($2) to get at least any graphs in my plot, since the other column didn't worked at all. You were right with the unix time which was a great help!

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much.